# jQuery plugin how to get value from function within the plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I am creting a plugin for `mysql` result including search filters and orders. I have created a plugin using some of tutorials and things are going fine for simple query with load more (youtube like).

Now I am trying to add filter options to the plugin and stuck with getting value from the one function to the `ajax();` on change the dropdown. The function is within the pluign function.

```
sort_order_by = function () {

    var selected_val = '';
    var orderby_val = '';

    // check for sort order
    $(settings.order_by_selector).change(function () {
        //selected_val = $('#sort_order_by option:selected').val();
        selected_val = $('option:selected', this).val();
        orderby_val = (selected_val == '' || selected_val == null) ? null : selected_val;

                console.log(orderby_val); // this gives me result on change

        return orderby_val;
    });

    return null;
},
...
load = function (start, count) {

  console.log(sort_order_by()); // this giving me null

  $.ajax({
      url: settings.source,
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {start: start, count: count, sort_order_by: sort_order_by()},
      success: function (data) {
          var items = data.items;

          if (items.length) {
              $(items).each(function (index, value) {
                  append(value);
              });

              stepped = stepped + count;
          }

          if (data.last === true) {
              finished();
          }
      }
  });

};
```

How I can get the value from the `sort_order_by` function to the `ajax` `data` to set as a query params

## Full Code

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.loadmore = function (options) {
        var self = this,

            settings = $.extend({
                source: '',
                step: 2,
                order_by_selector: '#sort_order_by'
            }, options),

            stepped = 1,
            item = self.find('.item'),
            items = self.find('.items'),

            sort_order_by = function () {

                var selected_val = '';
                var orderby_val = '';
                // check for sort order
                $(settings.order_by_selector).change(function () {
                    //selected_val = $('#sort_order_by option:selected').val();
                    selected_val = $('option:selected', this);
                    orderby_val = (selected_val == '' || selected_val == null) ? null : selected_val;

                    console.log(orderby_val);
                });

                return orderby_val;
            },

            finished = function () {
                self.find('.items-load').remove();
            },

            append = function (value) {
                var name, part;

                item.remove();

                for (name in value) {
                    if (value.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                        part = item.find('*[data-field="' + name + '"]');

                        if (part.length) {
                            part.text(value[name]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                item.clone().appendTo(items);
            },

            load = function (start, count) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: settings.source,
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {start: start, count: count, sort_order_by: sort_order_by()},
                    success: function (data) {
                        var items = data.items;

                        if (items.length) {
                            $(items).each(function (index, value) {
                                append(value);
                            });

                            stepped = stepped + count;
                        }

                        if (data.last === true) {
                            finished();
                        }
                    }
                });

            };

        if (settings.source.length) {

            self.find('.items-load').on('click', function () {
                load(stepped, settings.step);
                return false;
            });

            load(1, settings.step);
        } else {
            console.log('Source is require');
        }

    }
}(jQuery));
```

> ## For working code see my answer below or [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33462189/1053190)
>
> Overview: I have reset `stepped` value to `1` to recalculate on change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of this jQuery function .change()

Looking at this code:

```
$(settings.order_by_selector).change(function () {
    ....
    return orderby_val;
});
```

Its purpose is to add an event listener to your "order_by_selector" so that every time its value change, it will run the function f you give it.

So in your code, the sort_order_by function just add an event listener, and whenever you call it, it just return null.

I suppose you want to filter every time user select a different option, so the solution should be something like this:

```
$.fn.loadmore = function (options) {
  var self = this,
  ...
      load = function (start, count, orderby_val, isRequery) {
        $.ajax({
          url: settings.source,
          type: 'get',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {start: start, count: count, sort_order_by: orderby_val},
          success: function(data){
             if (isRequery){
                // clear old items
             }
             ...
          }
          ...
       });
     };

  $(settings.order_by_selector).change(function () {
    ...

    // Don't just return the value here, do something else, for ex call function load:
    load(start, count, orderby_val, true);

    return orderby_val;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, having trouble with multiple output. I mean it is appending to the existing result instead of requering. Please notice the coma on my code before `load = function()` so I am confused where to add my dropdown code?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you can just add a new parameter to function Load() indicate whether to requery or append, if it is requery, clear old items before calling append in your ajax callback.
And also you don't need to declare function sort_order_by(). I will modify my code.

Comment: This is quite working, but there is still one issue. `load more` link is behaving weird. If I load all items and then do filtering than no more `load more` links appears. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Okay so finally I have resolved the issue. Probably it could be better. If so please let me know

Comment: I'm not quite catch that, can you make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? I would like to see your HTML structure. If something disappear after using filtering, I'm guessing you have deleted it when trying to clear your old items list in ajax callback.

Comment: I have just fixed and added as an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33462189/1053190 I am thankful to you all. If you think you can optimize for better performance please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks can be added one time, you are adding them on each function call.
You should call load(start,count,sort_order_by)  from  $(settings.order_by_selector).change callback.

```
$(settings.order_by_selector).change(function () {
    //selected_val = $('#sort_order_by option:selected').val();
    selected_val = $('option:selected', this).val();
    orderby_val = (selected_val == '' || selected_val == null) ? null :    selected_val;
    load(start,count,orderby_val);
            console.log(orderby_val); // this gives me result on change

    return orderby_val;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but, I don't know why, This way it is not clearing the output but appending with the existing query

Answer (score 0):

I have solved and final code is here. Just in case if anyone want to use the same.

> I thankful to [Hp93](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4364358/hp93) and [Mohmoud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3477817/mahmoud) for their help. I appreciate
>   and it helped me to resolve the issue. All credits goes to them.

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.loadmore = function (options) {
        var self = this,
            orderby_val = 'userid',

            settings = $.extend({
                source: '',
                step: 2,
                order_by_selector: '#sort_order_by'
            }, options),

            stepped = 1,
            item = self.find('.item'),
            items = self.find('.items'),

            started = function () {
                self.find('.items-load').show();
            },

            finished = function () {
                self.find('.items-load').hide();
            },

            append = function (value) {
                var name, part;

                item.remove();

                for (name in value) {
                    if (value.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                        part = item.find('*[data-field="' + name + '"]');

                        if (part.length) {
                            part.text(value[name]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                item.clone().appendTo(items);
            },

            load = function (start, count, orderby_val, isRequery) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: settings.source,
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {start: start, count: count, sort_order_by: orderby_val},
                    success: function (data) {

                        if (isRequery) {
                            self.find('.item').remove();
                            stepped = 1;

                            //console.log(data.last);
                        }
                        var items = data.items;

                        if (items.length) {
                            $(items).each(function (index, value) {
                                append(value);
                            });

                            stepped = stepped + count;
                            console.log('loaded ' + stepped);
                        }

                        if (data.last === true) {
                            finished();
                        } else {
                            started();
                        }

                    }
                });

            };

        if (settings.source.length) {

            self.find('.items-load').on('click', function () {
                load(stepped, settings.step, orderby_val);
                return false;
            });

            load(1, settings.step, orderby_val);
        } else {
            console.log('Source is require');
        }

        $(settings.order_by_selector).change(function () {

            var selected_val = $('option:selected', this).val();
            var orderby_val = (selected_val == '' || selected_val == undefined) ? 'userid' : selected_val;

            load(1, settings.step, orderby_val, true);

            return orderby_val;
        });

    }
}(jQuery));
```