# json and php get data-field value in php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am struggling to use json object `data-field` attribute value in php function.

Here is the case

I am using infinite scroll and that script is loading json data directly on data-field` element.

For instance `data-field="username"`, `data-field="email"` and so on..

Here I have a php function `my_func($var1, $var2, $var3, ...)`. Here I want to use some of the `data-field` items something like below

```
my_func(data-field="username", data-field="email", ...);
```

> I know that I can't directly use `data-field` in php function, this was just for a reference.

***Note:*** I need infinte scroll so if I use `json_decode` than I may have to compromise with it. So I would prefer to find other way instead of using `json_decode` **if possible.**

Comment: `data-field` is a DOM element attribute. How about doing an ajax call passing those `data-field` values?

Comment: infinite scroll plugin link ?

Comment: @DeepakBiswal I am not sure how to do that with php function. Can you please provide me some hint?

Comment: @TouqeerShafi it's a custom plugin. Here is the code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33462189/1053190

Comment: If you are using jQuery then you can fetch `data-field` attr value in that or else in simple javascript you can get those values and then do an ajax call by passing those values. And then in ajax call execute `my_func` PHP function by using those passed values are param. Hope this will help.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal I am sorry but going top of my head. I am not jQuery expert so need little detailed direction. If you can help me would appreciate.

Comment: Do you know how to collect `data-field` in javascaript/jQuery?

Comment: Yes I do, that is what I have done in the plugin. Can we get on chat please

Comment: How to do that? I didn't see a chat option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93951/discussion-between-code-lover-and-deepak-biswal).